# Is it possible to run OSGi components within Weblogic 10.3?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, osgi, weblogic-10.x, application-server

Is it possible to run OSGi components within Weblogic 10.3? From what i have read it is not possible but im asking just to be 100% sure. There is no option to swap out WL 10.3 so there is no need to list any other application servers or OSGi containers.

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed an osgi container inside of WLS 10.3, then deploy your bundles inside it.

[Equinox in a Servlet Container](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_container.php)

It's pretty rough, but might be worth a look.

WLS 10.3 supports j2ee deployable libraries which can be used to modularize a large application.

Comment: I've done this and it works.  If there's never going to be the possibility of using a real OSGi-based server I'm not sure what the benefit of this approach is.

Comment: I actually agree with you Steven. I modified Tapestry to work within Equinox a couple of years ago in WLS, but it wasn't ready for production then, and I don't think it is now. Maybe WLS will start working allowing us to use OSGI bundles eventually. If you look at your 10.3 "modules" folder, you'll see that they've already partitioned into OSGI bundles.

Comment: Yes, all current mainstream JEE containers (except JBoss) are implemented using OSGi, it's just that OSGi is considered too scary for JEE guys to use, so it's not exposed.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by OSGi components ? If you mean a bundle, then you can certainly load it, since a bundle is just a .jar file with additional metadata. However you're not going to get the lifecycle events, and if the bundle depends on these to bind to additional services then you will have a problem.

Comment: Yes bundle. And I want to have lifecycle events fired.

Comment: I think in that case you'll have to run an OSGi container of some type *within* your Weblogic instance.